# How to retrieve the input parameter values of a stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create a auditing procedure which will be called in the catch block of all the procedure in my Database.

I wanted to store the list of all the input parameters and its values in this auditing DB.

Please suggest me, how to achieve this in SQL Server

Comment: Means u want to execute one procedure in catch block of all procedures ??

Comment: yes Krish Kvr, i am looking for some generic procedure which will be called from the catch block and the input of the procedure can be derived from some system procedure

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of programatically retrieving the list of parameters and their values for a stored proc(Possibly would involve n number of system tables and things like that). Without going into that level of complexity AND if altering the current procedures is a possibility, you could do something on the lines of below.

`ALTER` the existing stored procs to add a small functionality wherein you populate a table variable with
the parameters in a set string format(`'@paramname = paramvalue'`) and their values in the current proc 
and then fire the Auditing proc if the control reaches the `CATCH` block.

```
--Add this code bit on top of the proc from where you want the Audit Proc to be fired

--Declare and insert into a table variable
Declare @ParamValues TABLE (params varchar(400))

insert into @ParamValues
select '@id = '+ @id  UNION
select '@name  = '+ @name  UNION
select '@date = '+ @date

GO

...
....
END TRY

begin catch --Auditing proc code below
exec AuditDB.dbo.AuditProc @ParamValues, 
     OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) --this returns the name of current proc 
end catch

-------
-------Create the requisite SQL objects
-------
CREATE TABLE AuditDB.dbo.AuditTable
(
    AuditMessage varchar(400),
    ProcName varchar(200),
    DateTimeStamp DateTime
);
GO
CREATE TYPE AuditDB.dbo.ParamValuesType AS TABLE
(
    params varchar(400)
);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE AuditDB.dbo.AuditProc
    @ParamValues dbo.ParamValuesType READONLY
    ,@ProcName varchar(200)
AS

BEGIN --Add whaterver lines of code required, this is just a basic version.
    INSERT INTO AuditDB.dbo.AuditTable      
    SELECT params, @ProcName, cast(getdate() as datetime) FROM @ParamValues
END;
```

Comment: thanks sourav_Agasti for the suggestion. But the challenge here is to capture the table type variable information as well. Also there will be lot of code changes as most of the procedures are already implemented and i am trying to develop an logging system which can capture all input information to repro the issue. Please let me know if you have any other approach to proceed with it