# Capture the parameters and values of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to capture the parameters and values of a stored procedure in another SP without hardcoding them?

For example:

```
CREATE PROC sp_testProc
    @Par1 INT,
    @Par2 BIT,
    @Par3 NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
        /*Some payload*/
        SET @Par1 = @Par1 + 1
        SET @Par2 = 0
        SET @Par3 = 'a'
        /*An Error occurs*/
        /*Some more payload*/
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        /*Capture the procedure parameters and their values*/
    END CATCH
END
```

So far i have an idea how to get the parameters but not how to assign their current values.

The idea is to pass @@SPID to the procedure as a parameter and then use something like `SELECT @var=@var+name+' ,' FROM sys.parameters WHERE object_id = @@SPID`

So from this information i can build the folowing string:

`EXEC sp_testProc @Par1 = , @Par2 = , @Par3 =`

My goal is to build this string:

`EXEC sp_testProc @Par1 = 1, @Par2 = 0, @Par3 = 'a'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28065713/2993606

Comment: There the parameters are hard coded and if you red my post a bit carefully you will see that i dont want to hard code them.

Comment: Not asking you to look at the answer. Look at the question. It has the exact same requirement as yours.

Comment: Tell us your idea for getting the parameters. This will help us provide an answer on how to assign the values. Also, a less aggressive style of commenting against those that are trying to help might provide a better outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i thought about how this can be done and i wrote the following procedure:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('TheDropper') IS NOT NULL) DROP PROC TheDropper
GO

CREATE PROC TheDropper
    @ProcName NVARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DropScript NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT object_id FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@ProcName))
    SET @DropScript = 'DECLARE @ParamAndDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ParamAndDefinition = ''
EXEC '+@ProcName+' ''+'+CHAR(10)
    ELSE
    RAISERROR('The procedure you supplied does not exist',16,1)

    SELECT @DropScript = @DropScript +
    CASE WHEN b.name IN ('numeric','smallint','real','money','int','float','decimal','bit','bigint') THEN
        ''''+a.name+ ' = '' + ' + 'COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,' + a.name + '),''NULL'')+'', ''+'+CHAR(10)
    ELSE ''''+a.name+ ' = '''''' + ' + 'COALESCE(' + a.name + ',''NULL'')+''''''''+'', ''+'+CHAR(10)
    END
    FROM sys.parameters as a
    INNER JOIN sys.types as b ON a.system_type_id = b.system_type_id and b.name <> 'sysname'
    WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@ProcName)
    ORDER BY parameter_id

    SET @DropScript = LEFT(@DropScript,LEN(@DropScript)-7)

    PRINT @DropScript
END
GO

EXEC TheDropper 'sp_testProc'
```

How does it work:

You supply a procedure name you want to get the "exec procedure_name @params" statement of as a parameter to TheDropper.

After that you get a code generated which you paste above the TRY block in your procedure or just before any code at all.

This code practically generates a variable which contains all the parameter variables from your procedure.

In case of error you can use this variable in your CATCH block to store it an Error log table with all the error messages and what interest you.

Answer (score -1):

You can create another SP and a log table to store the execution logs of `sp_testProc`
and call that SP in the sp_testProc `CATCH` module. Let it stores the parameters, timestamp, reason for error etc of `sp_testProc` in that log table.

Comment: This part is clear to me without you bringing it up the problem is how to capture the parameters AND their values.

Comment: If you have BEGIN TRANSACTION in TRY module then ROLLBACK the transaction in CATCH module so that you can get the parameter values actually passed to the SP and you can store the parameter values to the log table.